# How to create a new list in a recursive F# function?

Tags: list, recursion, functional-programming, f#

I am creating a recursive function that will look at an existing list, and create a new list but with no duplicates. I'm removing the head of the existing list, and checking the new list to see if it contains that element. If it doesn't, then I add it because I know it's not a duplicate.

So far, I have this code.

```
let newList = []
let rec filtered inputList = 
  match inputList with
    | [] -> []
    | h::t -> if List.contains h newList then filtered t else h::(filtered t)
```

I know in my else statement I'm not prepending that element to newList. Is there a way I can do multiple lines of code in an if statement while using a match statement? How can I fix this?

Comment: If you're doing this for educational purpose then please keep going, but be aware that [`List.distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.distinct%5b't%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d) exists.

Answer (score 1):

In functional style programming normally you wouldn't append to a list but rather pass it around in the recursive function and return it at the end like this.

```
let distinct list =
    let rec filtered inputList outputList = 
      match inputList with
        | [] -> outputList
        | h::t -> if List.contains h outputList then (filtered t outputList) else (filtered t (h::outputList))

    filtered list []

printf "%A" (distinct [1; 2; 2; 3]) // [3; 2; 1]
```

I tried to keep as much as your original code as possible to make the difference more obvious. Basically you start the recursive function with an empty list and at the end it returns the list containing the unique elements.

Now this is more a question of style than anything, but I'd also break the if apart like this

```
let distinct list =
    let rec filtered inputList outputList = 
      match inputList with
        | [] -> outputList
        | h::t when List.contains h outputList -> filtered t outputList
        | h::t -> filtered t (h::outputList)

    filtered list []

printf "%A" (distinct [1; 2; 2; 3]) // [3; 2; 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution by dee-see has one nice property which is that it is tail-recursive. This means that it can easily handle very large lists.

However, if you are new to functional programming, it might be easier to start with a simpler version, which takes an input list and returns the output list directly as the result.

This is actually very close to what you have. The logic you need to implement is that:

- if there is an element in the rest of the list, then we skip it
- if the element is not in the rest of the list, we append it

For this, you do not need you `newList`. You can simply check `List.contains h t`, because that ensures you will only return the last occurrence of each duplicated element:

```
let rec filtered inputList = 
  match inputList with
  | [] -> []
  | h::t -> if List.contains h t then filtered t else h::(filtered t)

filtered [1;2;3;2;3;4;5;4;1]
```

The only difference from your function is in the condition. The solution by dee-see is more sophisticated, but it achieves the same result. As in the other answer, you can do this more elegantly using `when`:

```
let rec filtered inputList = 
  match inputList with
  | [] -> []
  | h::t when List.contains h t -> filtered t 
  | h::t -> h::(filtered t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
let rec distinct = function
    | []   -> []
    | h::t -> h :: distinct (List.filter ((<>) h) t)
```